# Memory leak org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader. The memory is accumulated in one instance of java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap (on wildfly)

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss, wildfly

I'm upgrading my version of JBoss, java and hibernate from

JBoss 6 to wildfly 11

hibernate 4 to hibernate 5.1

and java 6 to java 8

but I'm facing this problem with the java heap, the 79% of the memory is occupated by the ConcurrentHashMap object, I did a heap dump and with eclipse analyzer and I saw that the major error comes from this error

"The classloader/component "org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader @ 0x6c27d1230" occupies 2.877.603.336 (79,10%) bytes. The memory is accumulated in one instance of "java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Node[]" loaded by "system class loader".

and if I see the details, the Accumulated Objects in Dominator Tree show this:

```
org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader -> 2.877.603.336 (Retained Heap)

-java.util.Vector @ 0x6c27d4db0 -> 2.877.123.872 (Retained Heap)

--java.lang.Object[20480] -> 2.877.123.840 (Retained Heap)

---class org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryRegistry -> 2.840.910.848 (Retained Heap)

-----org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryRegistry -> 2.840.910.168 (Retained Heap)

------java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap -> 2.840.909.848 (Retained Heap)

-------java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Node[256]-> 2.840.909.784 (Retained Heap)
```

I really don't understand why this happens, because using the old technologies, not one this happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end was a bug in the code, i had a "reconnect" for every time that i had a NOT_ACTIVE status, this reconnect build new connections and generate a memory leak in the application.

Removing this reconnect and excluding the NOT_ACTIVE status was the solution for this problem.

Comment: I have similar problem. Could you elaborate the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The SessionFactoryRegistry keeps track of the SessionFactory created by your application. Normally you would only need one SessionFactory, it is expensive to create one.
Typically the SessionFactory is initialized at startup and the Session object is injected automatically. There are various ways to achieve that but you can start [here](https://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/docs/tutorial/1.0.7/html/Hibernate_Session_In_EJB3.html)